# Intiize the Custom object with empty string in java

Tags: java, string

I have adresss object with n filed .. while using it i want to intize 1 or 2 filed rest filed i want as -  ""
instead of null.

one way is manually adresss.setABC(" ") but do we have way to do it implictily ?

Comment: You can either assign it in the default constructor or can directly assign the instance variable (`private String abc = "";`)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Builder design pattern to create the Objects. Set only the mandatory attributes while creating the Objects. Rest all other fields will be null when not set. Please check https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/ on Builder design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Class variables (or member variables) of each data type has default values. For example,

```
int number;         // number will have default value: 0
float ratio;        // default value: 0.0
boolean success;    // default value: false
String name;        // default: null
Object obj;         // default: null
```

If you want to change this to some other value, you can change the member variable declaration or change the value in your class' constructor.

```
String name = "";
```

Declaring the above statement as class variable will ensure that the value is empty instead of null. Another way is to set it in class constructor,

```
public Address(){
  this.name = "";
}
```